# I am not able to import from Sheet2 to Sheet1 in VB Script in Excel while using INDEX MATCH function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in Column A and B in Sheet2 and I have taken some of data from Column A and paste them in column A in Sheet1 and now I want to import data from Sheet2 Column B for matched data of column A in both sheet. I have used below logic to do this but getting error.

```
For k=2 To 400

   Cells(k,2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet2!Range("B2:B1255"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(K, 1).Value, Sheet2!Range("A2:A1255")))

Next k
```

Answer (score 0):

### Index Match Formula in VBA

- In the second example, adjust the name of the destination worksheet (`Sheet1`) appropriately.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testFormula()
    With Range("B2").Resize(400 - Range("B2").Row + 1)
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B$2:B$1255," _
            & "MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A$2:A$1255,0)),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub


Sub testVBA()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Define Source Lookup Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Dim sLast As Long: sLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set srg = .Range("A2:A" & sLast) ' i.e. '.Range("A2:A1255")'
        ' Or just:
        'Set srg = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
    ' Define Destination Lookup Range.
    Dim drg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim dLast As Long: dLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set drg = .Range("A2:A" & dLast) ' i.e. '.Range("A2:A400")'
        ' Or just:
        'Set drg = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
    ' Loop through cells of Destination Lookup Range...
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim cIndex As Variant ' Can be an error value, hence 'Variant'.
    ' Loop through cells of Destination Lookup Range.
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        ' Attempt to find a match (the first occurrence) of the value
        ' in the current cell of Destination Lookup Range,
        ' in cells of Source Lookup Range.
        cIndex = Application.Match(dCell.Value, srg, 0)
        ' If a match is found...
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            ' Write the value from the cell associated (in the same row)
            ' to the matched cell (i.e. Source Column 'B'), to the cell
            ' associated (in the same row) to the current cell
            ' (Destination Column 'B').
            dCell.Offset(, 1).Value = srg.Cells(cIndex).Offset(, 1).Value
        ' IF no match found (error value)...
        Else
            dCell.Offset(, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    Next dCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any other way to without using Formula function?